# Are dunders methods or functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, magic-methods

I'm a bit confused with the use of methods like `__iter__()` and `__next__()` (I suppose they are called dunders).
I was trying to understand iterators and iterables and wrote this code:

```
x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
try:
    y = x.__iter__()
    while 1:
        print(y.__next__())
except StopIteration:
    print('Iterator has exhausted')
```

Then the code got executes without error when I used `__iter__` and `__next__` as functions:

```
x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
try:
    y = iter(x)
    while 1:
        print(next(y))
except StopIteration:
    print('Iterator has exhausted')
```

Can anybody tell me how they can be used as both a method and function? And is it applicable to all dunders?

Comment: [`iter` and `next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) are functions. [`__iter__` and `__next__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#container.__iter__) are methods.

Comment: so what you're saying is, __iter__() and __next__() are methods of object tuple (here) and next() and iter() are inbuilt functions. And this thing is not true for other dunders?

Comment: "And this thing is not true for other dunders?" What made you infer that? All dunders gave a separate implementation for each class that supports them, whole the associated built-in functions are just implemented once for all types.

Comment: You are not really supposed to actually call magic methods, that's why they may or may not be available for built-in types. However `iter(x)` in the second variant does provide you an iterator, so there you could use `y.__next__()`.

Comment: @tevemadar You contradicted yourself there! Once you've called `y = iter(x)`, you'll want to call `next (y)`, not `y.__next()__`.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying is not true for all dunders: if you have a method `x.__foo__()` then you can't necessarily call it with `foo()`. That's true, there is a predefined list of built-in functions that call the corresponding dunders. It's longer that just `iter` and `next` though e.g. also `list`, `bool`. Other dunders have other special meanings e.g. `x.__getitem__(y)` is called when you write `x[y]`.

Comment: @ArthurTacca it's simpler: I misunderstood the question and assumed the first code snippet did not work. (However what I wrote works fine too, you can use `y.__next__()` after `y=iter(x)`)

Answer (score 0):

- If you are writing your own class and want it to support being iterated over then write an `__iter__` method for it.
- If you are using a class that supports iteration then call the `iter` function (or, in most cases where you don't need so much control, just use it in a for loop).

This applied not only to this particular pair but also other dunder methods and associated functions e.g. `len()` and `__len__()`.

Under the hood, the `iter` function just calls the `__iter__` method of the object passed to it. You might ask: why, then, bother to have an `iter` function of you can just call the `__iter__` method yourself? (Maybe that's what you really wanted to know in the first place.) There are two reasons I can think of:

- It makes your code look a bit neater if you're calling a function without underscores.
- Often with these pairs of built-in functions and associated dunder methods, the built-in function actually takes care of a few different details. `iter` is an example of this: as the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) for it say, it works not only for types with an `__iter__` method but also those satisfying the container protocol (i.e. `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods).
- (Also, those underscores are meant to indicate that you aren't meant to call the method directly, but that explanation is a bit circular when you're already asking why not call them directly.)